# Difference between static casting styles in C++ for primitive values

Tags: c++, casting

Given:

```
int i = some_int_value();

double d1 = i;
double d2 = (double)i;    
double d3 = double(i);
double d4 = static_cast<double>(i);
```

Is there any difference between these casts in reality?

What if the cast was narrowing (`double` to `int`) instead of widening?

I've read that C++ should avoid use of C-style casts, though I'm not sure this applies to primitive values.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question that you can find if you follow the **Related** links.

Comment: @Barmar, I read through some of those questions/answers and didn't come away with an understanding of what I'm asking here. Can you point me at a specific answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, they are equivalent. You should prefer the C++-style casts (`static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `const_cast`) for all types, no matter if primitive or not, because you want to state your exact intention. The C-style cast is mightier than the others (taken individually) and should be avoided exactly for that reason.

If you apply a `static_cast` where it is not allowed, the compiler will complain. If you apply a C-style cast in the same situation, you may, for example, **silently** get a `reinterpret_cast` with undefined run-time behaviour instead of a compiler error.

Comment: When compiling with warnings about signed comparisons, it seems rather verbose to put `static_cast` everywhere. I'll give it a shot. Maybe it will encourage a change in design in a few places, hopefully for the better :)

Comment: The fact that the C++-style casts are hard to type is often considered an *advantage*. They remind you that frequent casting may indicate design errors.

Comment: @DrewNoakes On the other hand, it is easier to search for. This is actually stated as one of the motivations in one of Stroustrup's books.

Comment: Thanks all for the insight. I'm researching a good C++ book to buy and Stroustrup's get a lot of kudos, though they don't seem to be for everyone.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: You should also read Scott Meyers' Effective C++ and More Effective C++ books. Stroustrup is more about what you *can* do with the language, whereas Meyers is more about what you *should* do with it. Both aspects are important.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that a C-style cast will do *anything* to get its job done, even a conversion between unrelated types. `static_cast` has limited power, so if you try to do anything it can't do, you get an error.

You could say a C-style cast is like `reinterpret_cast`, except that you cannot cast away qualifiers like `const`.

Comment: Would you ever get an error converting between numeric types using static_cast though? I haven't seen one before.

Comment: @DrewNoakes No.  Converting between built in numeric types will not throw an error with `static_cast`.  They can all be implicitly casted.

Comment: Nope, you won't. But if you try to convert a `foo` into a `bar`, you will. A C-style cast lets you do that.

Comment: @faranwath: it's incorrect that a C-style cast is like reinterpret_cast. For example, you cannot cast const away with a reinterpret_cast, but you *can* with a C-style cast.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Edited accordingly.

Comment: @faranwath: I'm not sure, but does reinterpret_cast actually *guarantee* the same result as dynamic_cast if applied where a dynamic_cast would be well-defined?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I cannot answer that because I don't actually use `reinterpret_cast` all too often except to cast between pointers and integers. I suppose you could dive into the Standard, though.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a case where dynamic_cast works but reinterpret_cast is rejected by the compiler. Oh well, I guess it's just an academic question anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, these are all equivalent. They all perform a *standard conversion*, in particular a *floating-integral conversion*. They would also be equivalent if converting from `double` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
double d1 = i;
```

This will use implicit casting.

```
double d2 = (double)i;    
double d3 = double(i);
```

Those are identical C-style explicit casts.

```
double d4 = static_cast<double>(i);
```

This is the C++-style explicit cast.

From a practical standpoint, all of the explicit casts will do the same thing.  The `static_cast` operator has some checks to ensure the cast is actually valid (it will not compile if the cast is invalid) and makes it easier to find casts in your code.  If you wanted to force a cast (even if it is unsafe), you can use `reinterpret_cast`, which will trust you to know what you are doing (no error at compile time for invalid casts - and potentially undefined behavior if you do something really off the wall).

Comment: I suppose `static_cast` future proofs against changes in the type of the value being cast as well.

Comment: @DrewNoakes For an assignment like this, I'd stick with the implicit cast.  If you were to call a function that had an `int` and `double` overload, but you wanted the `double`, I'd use the `static_cast` in the function call.

Comment: As a person who generally prefers less verbose casting between primitive types, I'd also add that function-stlye cast (option 3) feels "safer" than traditional C-style (option 2) because it is explicit about *what* you are casting, so you'll never have to think about precedence. You can think about function-style cast as a trade-off between C-style and static_cast.

Comment: @Kirinyale I'm not sure I follow what you mean.  Can you explain further what you are trying to convey?

Comment: @Zac Howland It's in fact more of a "psychological" thing than actual safety (that's why I used the word "feels"). I am talking about the fact that although `(int) x + y` and `int(x) + y` are equivalent, the latter is explicit about the fact that only x is the target of the cast, and the first relies on the "implicit" precedence rules, which are pretty safe for type-casting, but have some other caveats like & and ==. Also, when you want to cast an expression, with `(int)(x + y)`, you need those extra parentheses anyway, so `int(x + y)` wins once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
double d1 = i;
```

This will warn you if there could be a data loss.

```
double d2 = (double)i;
```

This is a C style cast. @faranwath is correct that this is like reinterpret_cast, but also does a const_cast if needed.

```
double d3 = double(i);
```

This calls the double constructor with int argument, also will warn if data could be lost.

```
double d4 = static_cast<double>(i);
```

This suppresses the compiler warning and is easy to search for in your code. For my taste, this most clearly expresses your intent. In other cases than int->double, such as if const_cast were neeeded, the compiler would alert you to the problem with an error. That's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

As faranwath said, C-style casts will do anything to get the job done. The major difference is that static_cast is safe and tells the compiler exactly what you want to do and no more.